# Card.io Override frame getter

Tags: ios, swift, card.io

I'm using Card.io to scan cards inside a custom UIView. The issue I have is that the camera view is taking up the view frame resulting in borders left and right. There's a frame property called `cameraPreviewFrame` that assigns the window and I think I need to override this property and return it's width and height.

[image: Camera with current borders]

Is this possible or is there something else I need to do?

My current code is:

```
 var cardScanView: CardIOView = {
    let csv = CardIOView()
    csv.guideColor = .blue
    csv.hideCardIOLogo = true
    csv.allowFreelyRotatingCardGuide = false
    csv.backgroundColor = .purple
    return csv
}()
```

I'm adding this programatically inside a collection view cell and it does work in it's current form. Just the view is off.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like the camera view always uses a 4:3 form factor, making the solution above not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24360576/503750