# Frame of CardIO view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode8, cardio

I am working on an iOS app in Swift 3.0 and I have integrated card scanner using Card.IO for iOS.
I am successfully able to scan the card, but the problem is that width and height of the camera view does not take frames as per the requirements.
It only takes width and height in ratio of 3:4.

I want, the camera should take half of the screen height and full screen width, But is is not taking. When I pass the frame as

```
cardView = CardIOView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: screen.width, height: screen.height / 2))
```

it does not take full screen width.

Is it a bug on SDK side, I have tried everything but no success.
If anyone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you solve this issue?

Comment: Nope, its same..

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is: you incorrectly determine the screen size: [Swift: Determine iOS Screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110762/swift-determine-ios-screen-size)

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

Comment: Actually that is my custom logic and screen width and height are correct.

Comment: Screen width and height are saved at the time of app launch and are saved on app level.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340859/make-view-cover-full-screen-using-cgrectmake), [second](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/116), [third](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/180)